# ref.current.onSnapshot is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have this code:

```
export default function TestingComponent(firebaseApp) {
    firebase = firebaseApp;
    db = getFirestore();
    auth = getAuth();

    console.log(db);

    // Vx1JSJHadTWEyXloDVhY2GYd3e03
    
    console.log("getting data...")
    const [value, loading, error] = useDocumentData(doc(db, "users", "Vx1JSJHadTWEyXloDVhY2GYd3e03"));
```

all things are defined, `db`, `firebase` & `auth`.

The document path is correct, checked multiple times but I'm still getting an error:

> ref.current.onSnapshot is not a function

more particularly:
[image: this]

am I doing something wrong? this follows the documentation of

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being the wrong versrion of `react-firebase-hooks`, to have it work for the newest firebase SDK, use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase9-hooks)